# PHP Str_replace is not working in foreach loop

Tags: php, json, str-replace, steam-web-api

Here is my code.

I am trying to get inspect link for steam item. I have tried to use preg_replace but no luck either.

```
    $API_link =     sprintf("http://steamcommunity.com/id/*steamid*/inventory/json/730/2?trading=1");
    $json = file_get_contents($API_link);
    $json_output = json_decode($json);
    $result = $json_output;
    $link = array();
    $id = array();
    foreach($result->rgDescriptions AS $item){  
    $empty = array();   
    $newstring = $item->actions[0]->link;
    if($newstring == NULL){
        continue;
    } else {
    $empty['link'] = $newstring;

    array_push($link, $empty);
    }       
    }       
    foreach($result->rgInventory AS $inventory){

        $empty = array();
        if($inventory->instanceid == 0){
            continue;
        } else {
            $empty['id'] = $inventory->id;
            array_push($id, $empty);        
        }
    }

    $array = array_merge($id, $link);

    foreach($array AS $final){

        $assetid = "%assetid%";

        echo str_replace($assetid, $final['id'], $final['link']);

    }
```

}

But its not working. Please see if you can help.

Comment: May I ask what "not working" means in this case?

Comment: so you really need 3 loops through the same data?

Comment: You cannot get all the required data from just one $result. I need the asset id which is only in rgInventory and pass it to rgDescriptions with an array. This is my logical solution but there might be another way. I can echo $final['link'] and $final['id'] seperately but not in str_replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you have array of arrays:

```
// bracket squares equivalent of array() keyword PHP >=v5.4
// here is
// $link = array(['link'=>'url'],['link'=>'url'])
// $id   = array(['id'=>'id'],['id'=>'id'])

// result will be:
//   array(['link']=>'url'],['link'=>'url'],['id'=>'id'],['id'=>'id'])
$array = array_merge($id, $link);

foreach($array AS $final){
    // here is the first $final
    // array('link'=>'url')

    $assetid = "%assetid%";

    // but here is we try to get
    // 'id' and 'link'
    echo str_replace($assetid, $final['id'], $final['link']);
}
```

I think it's some kind of mistake.

Ok, some test script:

```
<?php

$a = array( array('link'=>'hello1'), array('link'=>'hello2'));
$b = array( array('id'=>'id0'), array('id'=>'id1'));
$c = array_merge($a, $b);
var_dump($c);
```

result:

```
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'link' =>
    string(6) "hello1"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    'link' =>
    string(6) "hello2"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    'id' =>
    string(3) "id0"
  }
  [3] =>
  array(1) {
    'id' =>
    string(3) "id1"
  }
}
```

array_merge doesn't mix your associative arrays between them nether all nor particular item (I hope I explain it correct)

of course

```
foreach ($c as $item) {
  var_dump($item);
}
```

will enumerate all the items one by one

```
  array(1) {
    'link' =>
    string(6) "hello1"
  }

  array(1) {
    'link' =>
    string(6) "hello2"
  }

  array(1) {
    'id' =>
    string(3) "id0"
  }

  array(1) {
    'id' =>
    string(3) "id1"
  }
```

and there is no array that has both of them (`link` and `id`) in the item

This script can't associate `link` and `id` properly, cause some of links can be skipped by `continue`, some of `id` also can be skipped. And it will be just a random list of available information. You can stuck in the next situation:

```
 - $links has first 10 links
 - $id has 3,4,5,7,9,11
```

It's just a list. Even if you have **only this pure info** (no other details), you can't properly associate it between of them by using shown source.

Here is minimum 1 simple solutions:

don't skip, don't merge, just add an empty array, and your final loop will be like this:

```
$assetid = "%assetid%";
for ($link as $key=>$final) {
  if (count($final) && count($id[$key])) {
    echo str_replace($assetid, $id[$key]['id'], $final['link']);
  } else {
     // some of needed arguments absent
  }
}
```

Comment: I made a new array from 2 new arrays. I think its possible

Answer (score 0):

Description not enough. Maybe try dump some variables?

```
foreach($array AS $final){

    $assetid = "%assetid%";

    //Check what is in $final
    var_dump($final);

    echo str_replace($assetid, $final['id'], $final['link']);

}
```

Comment: The information is inside the variables e.g I can echo them separately but they don't work in str_replace. Thanks

Comment: I wan to see **var_dump output** for one record and corresponding result of str_replace. So can you show me for one row otuput from vad_dump and st_replace?

And I hope that you know => these symbols are not wildcards here.

Comment: array(1) { ["id"]=> string(10) "4980712180" } 
array(1) { ["id"]=> string(10) "4980712003" }

Comment: array(1) { ["link"]=> string(112) "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D2450073139943621757" } 
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%AD2450073139943621757array(1) { ["link"]=> string(113) "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D16582832876545164542" } 
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%AD16582832876545164542

Comment: Something wrong is here. Is it **var_dump($final)**? Output should be array with min. **2** elements, not 1.

 
*array(1) {* .. should be *array(2) {*

Comment: Look for answer @Wizard - every elem your $final array has to be a array contains 2 elements, with keys 'id' and 'link' in this foreach.

I asked at the beginning of the dump variables to rest a lot of time.. I suggest read more about arrays in PHP and arrays functions. And remember => always check value of yours variables when debuging, not once, not double, but more times..